# Iterating over JSON and creating DIV tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsf, html

I have the following things with me. I have a JSON array containing some values. I basically used the JSON-lib to convert from a List to JSONArray using some groovy classes. Now, I have a JS file, and a JSF for the front end.

I need to iterate over the JSON array in the JS file and for each item in the array, I need to create a new div tag in the JSF page and call a corresponding JS function to populate the div tag.

Could someone help me with this? I am just not sure about how to iterate over the JSON Array and create the div tags. I have the functions to populate the div tags with me already.

Any help would be appreciated.

I am trying to do something like this

```
Reports.generateCharts = function generateCharts(){
  var jsonDeviceArr = {"Devices" :'${reportViewproto.selectedDevices}'};

  $.each(jsonDeviceArr, function(i, val){
    function create_div(){
      var cid = "chart"+i;
      dv = document.createElement('div');
      dv.setAttribute('id', cid);
      dv.style.position="center";
      dv.style.pixelLeft=20;
      dv.style.pixelTop=100;
      dv.style.pixelWidth=10;
      dv.style.pixelHeight=20;
      dv.attachEvent("onload", 
      function(){
        generateSparkLine(cid, '');
      });
      document.forms[0].appendChild(dv);
    }
  });
}
```

where 'reportViewprot' is a bean that has a function 'getSelectedDevices()' which would return the JSON array. Now this function 'generateCharts()' is present in a separate JS file and the div tags has to be loaded, when the JSF page is loaded.

This doesn't work though. Am I missing something here?

Hope I am clear.

Thanks,S.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery you should use [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/). Its a generic iterator function, which can be used to seamlessly iterate over both objects and arrays.

Example:

```
$.getJSON('ajax/test.json', function(data) {   
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        $("#parent").append("<div>" + function(key, value) + "</div>");
    });        
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have used jquery.each() to iterate. Could you look into my code and tell me where I could possible be going wrong? I have edited my question.

Comment: Why are you using the function create_div? Whats the error message?

Comment: @Diago - if i want to retrive json data from different json file and append to different div what should we do?

Comment: @Kamal could you please create a new question with that? Thanks.

Comment: @Diago here is similar question posted, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251721/problem-running-multiple-instances-of-a-plugin

Answer (score 0):

Two points:

1. Nobody seems to be calling the "create_div" function. Why don't you just remove that function wrapper?
2. Your onload function is trapping "dv" in a closure, which used to cause memory leaks on some browsers (maybe still does).

You can use jQuery to fetch the form object, and then use the append function (as Diogo did) to create your div on that as either pure HTML (in string form) or by daisy-chaining jQuery functions like append, css, bind, etc... Check the jQuery website for examples.

Doing it that way would avoid the closure problem, and would probably be cleaner to read.